# Magento registration not completed , $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer) empty

Tags: magento-1.7

I am getting a problem at the time of account creation in magneto. it starts loading and not redirect on index page but data saved in database and redirect URL is empty  when i checked.
Even not send account confirmation mail if required confirmation enabled.
please help and tell me what setting should be done here because it's working on local but not on live.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the custom extension for that registration.
Or, the AccountController might be rewritten by the other module.
Please check it ( \app\code\core\Mage\Customer\controllers\AccountController.php )

createPostAction()

And also, in your site the magento session might not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i got the solution as in app\code\core\Mage\Customer\controllers\AccountController.php  $url = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer); was empty so i replaced it with $url = Mage::getBaseUrl()."customer/account/index/"; and it's working.